# The use of verification code from php google sheet auth 2.0

Tags: php, google-apps-script

I refer to the article https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php, I can successfully execute the `php quickstart.php` from the command line, I copy and paste the URL to browser but cannot get the verification code. Finally, I add `echo $_REQUEST['code']` in my php script I set in **Authorised redirect URIs** setting, I can get the verification code.

What is the use of this verification code in the live system? Should I keep it in a safe place for later use?

Answer (score 0):

Verification code is a part of login system for an extra layer of security. It can protect from misuse of your account if someone have your password, because logging into your account always require a security code (this **verification code** is uniquely designed for your account, if you opt for verification code, an unique code is sent to your mobile for every 30-60 seconds) in the second step after you enter your password. Check this [link](https://www.9lessons.info/2016/06/google-two-factor-authentication-login.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Jess, do I need to frequently check the verification code in order to keep things done?